# PHP, redirect after form submission

Tags: php

I am very new to coding and I am trying to fix my form so it redirects to another webpage after the user submits.  I have read the other threads but I cannot get it to work.  Here is the code, and any help would be great!

```
$recipient = "#@gmail.com";

$subject = "User Sign Up Form";
$mailheader = "From: $user_email \r\n";
echo "Thank You! Submitted Successfully.";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

?>

Comment: You have no redirect code in there. How do you expect it to happen? Magic?

Comment: If the answer provided was correct, consider marking it as correct so the question gets closed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
header('location: example.php');
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks, when I add that under the echo and test, I see the echo and am not redirected.

Comment: There must not be any output before redirection. Remove your echo before header.

Comment: @FastPointMike Please mark this as correct if it fixed the problem.